# In what order does Hibernate persist children list with Cascade.ALL?

Tags: hibernate, hibernate-mapping

I have entity A that has child list of B entities annotated with Cascade.ALL. Entity ids are generated. When I persist entity A, which entity in list B will be saved first? Given B list looks like this: B1, B2, B3, B4, can I assume it will first save B1, then B2, etc? Therefore, B1 will always have the smallest id, because it will be saved first?

I'm experiencing weird behaviour when I'm retrieving saved entity A. My child list of B entities have @OrderBy(value = "id desc") to ensure the newest entity is always first, but in practice, the child list B in entity A seem to order randomly.

Comment: May I ask why this matters to you?  Databases don't really have an internal order, and assuming your list of objects is being inserted in a transaction, either all will be inserted or the whole thing will be rolled back.

Comment: The answer is in the last part of the question: my collection has OrderBy by id descending annotation, to ensure the newest entity is always first, but in practice I'm sometimes getting older entity first.

Answer (score 0):

The `@OrderBy` annotation controls the order in which a collection to which it is attached gets *retrieved*.  It does not control the order of insertion.  From the [documentation](https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/jpa/2.1/api/javax/persistence/OrderBy.html):

> Specifies the ordering of the elements of a collection valued association or element collection at the point when the association or collection is retrieved.

As the ever wise @a_horse_with_no_name commented, you should not be relying on any notion of internal "order" coming from Hibernate (which really just sits on top of your database).  If you need to preserve some order existing in your Java `List` during insertion, then you should create a property (column) for this very purpose.

Comment: Indeed, that is not what I was implying. Perhaps I wasn't clear enough. I persist entity A with child list of B entities. It is important how Hibernate saves child list of B entities (does it save the first one first, or the last one first? or randomly?), because this will affect how the entities will be retrieved later - since they are ordered by descending id. I.e. the entity that was saved the last, will be the first in the retrieved list.

Comment: I doubt what you are saying, though I'm not Gavin King.

Comment: @kikovi: The insertion order has not influence at all on the _retrieval_ order. Rows in a relational database are ***NOT*** "sorted". It does not matter in which order they are inserted. What matters is the proper `order by` when _retrieving_ them.

Comment: I agree the rows in the relational database are not sorted. However the insertion order matters, especially if the order by is by id, as in my case. For example, the first inserted entity will get id 1 upon saving, the second one will get id 2 and so on. Retrieving these entities with order by id will fetch list where the first entity will have id 1 and the second one will have id 2. If the insertion order changed, the retrieved list order will also change.

Comment: Nope.  You should NOT be relying on the DB to order anything.  Instead, use a field in the Java entity which can remember the order of an element in the list.

Comment: I DON'T rely on DB to order anything. I am relying on the id column of the entities, that Hibernate assigns automatically.

Comment: Then stop doing that.  Take control of the order by not using the default Hibernate/DB id.  This will be my last comment.